# I can't create a tag with spaces

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tags

I create a question but I can't use a tag with spaces. Is there a way to create a tag with spaces such as `development model`?

Comment: "It's a feature, not a bug"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spaces are not allowed in tags. Use a hyphen, like [development-model](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development-model).